# How to generate plist in cocos2d-x

Tags: plist, cocos2d-x

I want to write plist file from the code. That i want create a plist file and write some information into plist and save it in to the phone.

One more thing If I have a plist the how I can change value in the plis list from the code.

Comment: Context please! Do you want to write the plist on iOS only? If so, put your data in a NSArray/NSDictionary (or other collection) and use its writeToFile function and to read back use dictionaryWithContentsOfFile etc.

Answer (score 0):

I Use Cocos2D-X 2.2.1. If you are using 3.x it may has alternatives.

1. Use CCDictionary or CCArray you get writeToFile Function.
2. In argument of writeToFile function you have to pass path of the file where you have to write. (usually it is DOCUMENT_PATH). By this you can create "plist" file.
3. If you want to read plist data again you get function createWithContentsOfFile in CCDictionary and similar method in CCArray also. After changing you can just overwrite the 
   data from wherever you are reading.
   (If file is in bundle overwriting is not possible.)